# How to calculate p-value to compare AUPRC for two models?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, p-value, roc, precision-recall

I've built two deep learning models and was looking for a way to compare the two models in terms of the area under the precision recall curve terms. I know that the DeLong method is recommended for ROC comparisons, and it's what I've used to compare the AUROC of the two models, but I'm not sure how to implement something similar for AUPRC comparisons.

I've tried bootstrapping the metric 2000 times, but I'm not sure what type of hypothesis testing to use and don't want to violate any underlying assumptions of the test.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced a similar issue and implemented a simple **bootstrap-based method** (so not DeLong's test) to test the hypothesis that the real difference in PR AUCs is different than zero, see the `pr.test()` function in the [usefun](https://github.com/bblodfon/usefun) `R` package. See the statistic I used [here](https://github.com/bblodfon/usefun/blob/main/R/pr.R#L96).

Answer (score 0):

Concordance probabilities ($c$ index; AUROC) are not sensitive enough to lead to good power for comparing models.  Differences in AUROC are the same as differences in two Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test statistics and we don't do that.  See [this](https://fharrell.com/post/addvalue) for sensitive, simple, and interpretable measures and note that likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ tests are the gold standards in frequentist modeling.  Also see [this](https://hbiostat.org/bib/r2.html).

I think of the $c$-index (and its special case the AUROC) as useful pure discrimination measures for single models and not useful for comparison.  Concordance probabilities do not sufficiently reward extreme predictions that are right.

Measures such as the ones I'm advocating here also lend themselves to quantifying partial effects of predictors, i.e., how much a predictor or a set of predictors contributes to explaining variation in Y.

Related to insensitivity of concordance probabilities (they are tied down to be in [0,1]) another reason not to do statistical tests on them is that their distributions are very strange and normal approximations that are frequently used are not accurate enough.

Comment: What about for the PR curve?

Comment: Same loss of power, and like ROC curves provides very little insights while inviting dangerous dichotomizations.